# Windows Server Backup: Is it possible to backup a mapped drive?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-backup

Windows Server Backup: Is it possible to add a mapped drive to a scheduled backup (to back up from)

I can currently see only local drives and Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The way Windows Server Backup is designed<sup>1</sup>, it will only let you back up local drives. You can use network shares as a *backup destination*, but you cannot include a network share as a backup item.

You might want to consider a [*robocopy* script](https://superuser.com/questions/814102/robocopy-command-to-do-an-incremental-backup) to your backup destination as an alternative. If you need a history similar to Windows Server Backup's, just add VSS snapshots to the mix which can be created either immediately after the `robocopy` run using [`diskshadow`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772172.aspx) or using a schedule which you can create in the "Shadow copy" tab of your backup disk's properties

Backing up a *"mapped drive"* instead of an UNC remote location will introduce additional complications: mapped drives do not exist outside of the logged on user's session. So you either would need to run the backup from within this very session (typically not an option with servers) or recreate the mapping in your backup run context - where you would need to know the UNC path of the location and not just the mapped drive's name.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Windows Server Backup heavily relies on Shadow copies, which are usually not available for remote share destinations. Also, it basically is creating a vhd/vhdx image of the source device, not copying file-by-file as traditional file copy and backup solutions would do.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.   You can easily backup a mapped share by installing the older NTBackup  (Windows Backup) from any convenient Windows XP or Windows XP 64 bit and using that  (ignore the error about a storage device not being present and turn off VSS)

See the following:

http://smallvoid.com/article/win7-ntbackup-install.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your post needs to be expanded (see [answer]). It should include specific instructions ([not just links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to include the steps necessary to implement your answer (linking to source material for purposes of proper attribution is of course encouraged).

Answer (score -2):

You can backup to a shared folder.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd851825.aspx

Comment: I mean backup FROM a shared folder :)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.